# How to connect Primefaces UI and JavaScript components in tags

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i´m not able to address my JavaScript component to the primefaces attributes i have. It shouldn´t be a problem to address..

```
<h:header>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapx = goomap.getMap();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document
                .getElementById('form:layout:center:DataTablePanel:car2go'), mapx);
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
        //i previously created taxi data and filled it
            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data : pointArray
            });

            heatmap.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

and the body where i get the address of my attributes from:

```
<h:body>

<h:form id="form">

    <p:layout id="layout">


        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center" size="70%">


            <p:outputPanel id="DataTablePanel">



                    <p:gmap id="car2go" center="37.782551, -122.445368" zoom="13"
                        type="HYBRID" style="width:600px;height:400px" widgetVar="goomap"
                        fitBounds="true" />
            </p:outputPanel>


        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to your element from javascript/jQuery and you're not sure what's the client-id would be, always try to [inspect the element](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements) and see the final Id.

In your case the only `UINamingContainer` is the form, hence your gmap id is  `form:car2go`

```
.getElementById('form:car2go'), mapx);
```

*One note:* as I have seen that your script runs in the header, you might not have the chance to access the element yet, so it's better to place in the `$(document).ready` or before the end of the `<h:body>`